# Increment Up Only When Gap In Dates (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data structured like this:

| ID | Begin Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2023 | 2/1/2023 |
| 1 | 2/2/2023 | 2/15/2023 |
| 1 | 2/20/2023 | 9/21/2023 |
| 1 | 9/22/2023 | 10/11/2023 |
| 2 | 1/11/2023 | 4/11/2023 |
| 2 | 5/9/2023 | 6/15/2023 |
| 2 | 7/7/2023 | 9/17/2023 |

I would like partition by the ID and create a row number that only increments up when there is a gap between the end of one row and the beginning of the next (within the ID group).

The desired outcome looks like this:

| ID | Begin Date | End Date | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/1/2023 | 2/1/2023 | 1 |
| 1 | 2/2/2023 | 2/15/2023 | 1 |
| 1 | 2/20/2023 | 9/21/2023 | 2 |
| 1 | 9/22/2023 | 10/11/2023 | 2 |
| 2 | 1/11/2023 | 4/11/2023 | 1 |
| 2 | 5/9/2023 | 6/15/2023 | 2 |
| 2 | 7/7/2023 | 9/17/2023 | 3 |

Where a new group is created each time there is a gap in dates, but the group continues for as long as there is no gap in dates.

I have used a lead/lag function to calculate gaps, but I cannot figure out how to do this conditional incrementing in Oracle SQL Developer. Please, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired outcome in Oracle SQL, you can use the LAG function to compare the current row's Begin Date with the previous row's End Date within each ID partition. Based on the comparison, you can then use the SUM window function with a CASE statement to increment the Group when a gap is detected.

Here's an example query:

```
WITH DateRanges AS (
  SELECT
    ID,
    "Begin Date",
    "End Date",
    LAG("End Date") OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "Begin Date") AS PrevEndDate
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT
  ID,
  "Begin Date",
  "End Date",
  SUM(CASE WHEN "Begin Date" > NVL(PrevEndDate, TO_DATE('1900-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY "Begin Date") AS Group
FROM DateRanges;
```

Answer (score 0):

From Oracle 12, you can use `MATCH_RECOGNIZE` to perform row-by-row pattern matching:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
  PARTITION BY id
  ORDER BY begin_date
  MEASURES
    MATCH_NUMBER() AS grp
  ALL ROWS PER MATCH
  PATTERN (consecutive_dates* last_date)
  DEFINE consecutive_dates AS end_date + INTERVAL '1' DAY = NEXT(begin_date)
)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, Begin_Date, End_Date) AS
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-01-01', DATE '2023-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-02', DATE '2023-02-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-02-20', DATE '2023-09-21' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, DATE '2023-09-22', DATE '2023-10-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-01-11', DATE '2023-04-11' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-05-09', DATE '2023-06-15' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, DATE '2023-07-07', DATE '2023-09-17' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | BEGIN_DATE | GRP | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 1 | 2023-02-01 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-02-02 00:00:00 | 1 | 2023-02-15 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-02-20 00:00:00 | 2 | 2023-09-21 00:00:00 |
| 1 | 2023-09-22 00:00:00 | 2 | 2023-10-11 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-01-11 00:00:00 | 1 | 2023-04-11 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-05-09 00:00:00 | 2 | 2023-06-15 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 2023-07-07 00:00:00 | 3 | 2023-09-17 00:00:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ffXIBbmV)